# Can I use join in Entity Framwork Pagination syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pagination

I was wondering if someone can help here.I'm new to Entity Framwork. I have 2 different Query.I want to join them and get 1.Here is my code:

```
 public static List<BankDepositHistory> GetAllByPagination(int page ,int stepes)
        {

            page=page-1;

            using(MyketAdsEntities context = new MyketAdsEntities())
            {
                var transactionlist = context.BankDepositHistories.ToList();
                var start = page * stepes;
              var result=  context.BankDepositHistories.OrderByDescending(c=>c.AccountId)

                    //anny code that give me count as field
                    .Skip(start)
                    .Take(stepes)
                    .ToList();
                return (result);

            }
        }
        public static int GetCount()
        {
            using (MyketAdsEntities context = new MyketAdsEntities())
            {
                int count = context.BankDepositHistories.Count();
                return count;
            }

        }
```

As you see I have 2 method. I just want to have GetAllByPagination.
Many thanks

Comment: Do you want a method which just returns `Count` or do you want a method which returns both `Count` and `List` ?

Comment: @stom I want both count and list togther as a list.

Comment: This line appears to do nothing but make a wasteful extra call to the database: `var transactionlist = context.BankDepositHistories.ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have below Entity, Then below setup should work.

```
public BankDepositHistory
{

public string UserName {get;set}

//etc..

}
```

**Create a View Model**

```
public class BankDepositHistoryVM
{

public List<BankDepositHistory> bankDetails {get;set;}

public int Count {get;set;}

}
```

**Return View Model**

```
 public static List<BankDepositHistoryVM> GetAllByPagination(int page ,int stepes)
    {

        page=page-1;

        using(MyketAdsEntities context = new MyketAdsEntities())
        {
            var transactionlist = context.BankDepositHistories.ToList();
            var start = page * stepes;
          var result=  context.BankDepositHistories.OrderByDescending(c=>c.AccountId)
                .Skip(start)
                .Take(stepes)
                .ToList();

  List<BankDepositHistoryVM> resultVM = new List<BankDepositHistoryVM>();

  resultVM.bankDetails = result;
  resultVM.Count = result.Count();

            return resultVM;

        }
    }
```

**Call the method:**

```
List<BankDepositHistory> bankDetails = className.GetAllByPagination.bankDetails;

int count = className.GetAllByPagination.Count;

List<BankDepositHistoryVM> allDetails = className.GetAllByPagination();
```

Hope helps.

Comment: Many thanks,I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but it could be handy.

Comment: Welcome, If it helped you kindly [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.